# How to stylize KML layers for Google Maps?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml, google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

I am using QGIS 2.0 to convert my shapefiles into KML layers.

The purpose of converting my shapefiles into KML layers is to bypass the restriction imposed by Google Fusion Maps, which only allows one fusion table to be stylized.

However, I’m having issues retaining the layer style when exporting my shapefiles to KML layers. I’ve tried modifying the style tag found in the XML file, but nothing changes.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to stylize KML layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this little smart software: http://www.zonums.com/shp2kml.html
Don't forget to export your shapes into wgs84 coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with QGIS 2.8.2, it's not possible, see [this bug](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/3019).

There was a plugin (not updated anymore), qgis2kml, but it's compatible only with QGIS 1.8.0. You can try this old version and use the plugin from [here](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2kml/).

Comment: I'm having difficulties finding an older version of QGIS 1.8.0 for windows. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: Download the [zip package from here](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2kml/) clicking 0.2 on the tab "Versions" and unzip it on your python plugins directory, if you have windows it is on `%APPDATA%\.qgis\python\plugins`

Comment: 1) Download the [zip package from here](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2kml/) clicking 0.2 on the tab "Versions"